# get selected file size, from chooser plugin Cordova/Ionic

Tags: angular, cordova, ionic-framework

I am trying to select a file using [Chooser](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/chooser) plugin in Cordova/Ionic5.

I am able to get file and dataURI, but how can I get the selected file size.

Please help.

Comment: is it for ios or for android

Comment: Both. Format, i am getting. Filr uri, not size

Comment: I have added my comment below . i have tested this on android only i dont have ios device so you can test it on ios it will work for you in case of any issue please let me know

Answer (score 4, accepted):

File chooser plugin is for File selection.. it will not provide you file information like size mimetype etc.. you need some other plugin like `file` and `filepath` to fetch this information from file . I have mentioned these links below and have added my sample code how you can fetch this information via these plugins please check.

**constructor**

```js
import { FileChooser } from '@ionic-native/file-chooser/ngx';
import { FilePath } from '@ionic-native/file-path/ngx';
import { File } from '@ionic-native/file/ngx';

constructor(
        private fileChooser: FileChooser,
        private filepath : FilePath,
        private file : File,
        private plt : Platform
    
    ) { }
```

**File selection function**

```js
async selectFile(){
    
    if(this.plt.is('android')){
const selectedFile : string = await this.fileChooser.open();
        const resolvedPath = await this.filepath.resolveNativePath(selectedFile);
        const fileEntry = await this.file.resolveLocalFilesystemUrl(resolvedPath) as any;
        fileEntry.file((fileInfo)=>{
            console.log('File Info ', fileInfo);
            //sample response file mime type size etc you can use it as per your requirement
            // end: 3028
            // lastModified: 1610953273000
            // lastModifiedDate: 1610953273000
            // localURL: "cdvfile://localhost/sdcard/Download/sample.pdf"
            // name: "sample.pdf"
            // size: 3028
            // start: 0
            // type: "application/pdf"
        })
    }else{
        //For ios device 
        const selectedFile : string = await  this.filePicker.pickFile() ;
        const fileEntry = await this.file.resolveLocalFilesystemUrl('file:///'+selectedFile) as any;
        fileEntry.file((fileInfo)=>{
             console.log('File Info ', fileInfo);
        })
    }
}
```

https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/file

https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/file-path

Comment: for android working OK, in IOS, it is crashing the ionic-app

Comment: ooh my bad .. sorry but just to let you know `filechooser` is for android only

Comment: you need to use `filepicker` plugin for ios .. so i guess you can use the current function for android and for ios you can create a new function

Comment: i have installed iosFilePicker with ionic-native etc, but still app is crashing on you code. BAsically fileEntry.file() is crashing the app.  selectedFile variable is like this in console  :   /Users/mymac/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/F8F5EFB6-A10F-473E-9E73-DAE02F757CE3/data/Containers/Data/Application/61DECCBE-1EB0-43F1-A1D9-A6BE6CE08FD4/tmp/io.ionic.starter-Inbox/1610957484717.pdf

Comment: https://github.com/jcesarmobile/FilePicker-Phonegap-iOS-Plugin please check this link ..you need to update some config in your apple account inorder to use this plugin .. its just because of the icloud access .. please read this document

Comment: ya thanks, so that means without AppleDeveloper paid account we cant get fileMetadata on IOS. Because that plugin required ICloud etc.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/227477/discussion-between-taylor-rahul-and-raju).